# Adding new post format on plugin activation

Tags: post-formats

I am adding a new post format on my plugin activation using this code:

```
wp_insert_term( 'post-format-interviews_ans', 'post_format' );
```

It's not working. The rest of the plugin activation code, like table generation, is working.

`post_format` is a WordPress default taxonomy type.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the other taxonomies, you cannot use `wp_inset_term()` to add terms to the `post_format`  taxonomy as you cannot add new terms to this taxonomy.

You need to add the terms for the `post_format` via [`add_theme_support()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Formats), something like

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'gallery' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

[Post Formats](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) aren't like other taxonomies, they are fixed and new ones can't be added.

> New formats cannot be introduced by themes or even plugins. The standardization of this list provides both compatibility between numerous themes and an avenue for external blogging tools to access this feature in a consistent fashion.